# Adding a Object Array in a Array into a JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I had this JSON:

```
"event": [
{
  "timestamp": "2016-10-02T11:37:31.2300892-03:00",
  "revenue": 120.0,
  "transaction_id": "3409340",
  "store_name": "BH Shopping",
  "products": []
}
```

And this Object Array:

```
[ { name: 'Blue Shirt', price: 100 },
  { name: 'Nike Shoes', price: 150 } ]
```

How can I add the Object Array into the products Array inside the JSON using Javascript?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: first step is to parse the JSON into an object ... then it's easy working with javascript objects .. `parsedJSONvariable.event[0].products = whateverVariableHoldsYourObjectArray`

Comment: i think it is already a js object

Comment: Then it's not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this solution of adding objects to object property:

```js
var jsonStr = '{"event": {"timestamp": "2016-10-02T11:37:31.2300892-03:00", "revenue": "120.0",  "transaction_id": "3409340",  "store_name": "BH Shopping",  "products": []}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
obj['event']['products'].push({"name":"Blue Shirt","price":"100"});
obj['event']['products'].push({"name":"Nike Shoes","price":"150"});
jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, `event` is a `JSON Array` on its own so to target the first one you will have to pict JSON Object at `index 0`.

```
var eventObject = event[0];
```

Now the products is an array and you can push staff into it by iterating over your Object Array

```
objectArray.forEach(function(object){
    //the object is each array item
    eventObject.products.push(object);
});
```